# Expresso Store not saving {order_email} to database

Tags: expresso-store

I'm having an issue with Store not saving {order_email} to the database.

This is the only field not saving to orders. The checkout process fully completes. Order confirmation emails are not sending due to the field being blank.

```
{exp:store:checkout
form_class="form-horizontal"
next="store/checkout3"
error_handling="inline"
error_delimiters='<span class="help-inline">|</span>'
require="name|address1|city|country|state|order_email"
secure="yes"
}

{if no_items}
    {redirect="store/checkout"}
{/if}

<div class="col five first payForm">

<fieldset id="billing_details">
    <h3>Billing Details</h3>

    <div class="control-group {if error:billing_name}error{/if}">
        <label class="control-label" for="billing_name">Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
            {field:billing_name} {error:billing_name}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group {if error:billing_address1}error{/if}">
        <label class="control-label" for="billing_address1">Address</label>
        <div class="controls">
            {field:billing_address1} {error:billing_address1}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group {if error:billing_address2}error{/if}">
        <div class="controls">
            {field:billing_address2} {error:billing_address2}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group {if error:billing_city}error{/if}">
        <label class="control-label" for="billing_city">City</label>
        <div class="controls">
            {field:billing_city} {error:billing_city}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group {if error:billing_state}error{/if}">
        <label class="control-label" for="billing_state">State</label>
        <div class="controls">
            {field:billing_state} {error:billing_state}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group {if error:billing_postcode}error{/if}">
        <label class="control-label" for="billing_postcode">Postcode</label>
        <div class="controls">
            {field:billing_postcode} {error:billing_postcode}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group {if error:billing_country}error{/if}">
        <label class="control-label" for="billing_country">Country</label>
        <div class="controls">
            {field:billing_country} {error:billing_country}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group {if error:billing_phone}error{/if}">
        <label class="control-label" for="billing_phone">Phone</label>
        <div class="controls">
            {field:billing_phone} {error:billing_phone}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group {if error:order_email}error{/if}">
        <label class="control-label" for="order_email">Email</label>
        <div class="controls">
            {field:order_email} {error:order_email}
        </div>
    </div>

</fieldset>

</div><!-- end five -->

<div class="col five">

<fieldset>
    <h3>Shipping Details</h3>

    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <label for="shipping_same_as_billing" class="checkbox">
                {field:shipping_same_as_billing} Same as Billing Details
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="shipping_details_drawer">

        <div class="control-group {if error:shipping_name}error{/if}">
            <label class="control-label" for="shipping_name">Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                {field:shipping_name} {error:shipping_name}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group {if error:shipping_address1}error{/if}">
            <label class="control-label" for="shipping_address1">Address</label>
            <div class="controls">
                {field:shipping_address1} {error:shipping_address1}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group {if error:shipping_address2}error{/if}">
            <div class="controls">
                {field:shipping_address2} {error:shipping_address2}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group {if error:shipping_city}error{/if}">
            <label class="control-label" for="shipping_city">City</label>
            <div class="controls">
                {field:shipping_city} {error:shipping_city}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group {if error:shipping_postcode}error{/if}">
            <label class="control-label" for="shipping_postcode">Postcode</label>
            <div class="controls">
                {field:shipping_postcode} {error:shipping_postcode}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group {if error:shipping_state}error{/if}">
            <label class="control-label" for="shipping_state">State</label>
            <div class="controls">
                {field:shipping_state} {error:shipping_state}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group {if error:shipping_country}error{/if}">
            <label class="control-label" for="shipping_country">Country</label>
            <div class="controls">
                {field:shipping_country} {error:shipping_country}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group {if error:shipping_phone}error{/if}">
            <label class="control-label" for="shipping_phone">Phone</label>
            <div class="controls">
                {field:shipping_phone} {error:shipping_phone}
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</fieldset>
</div><!-- end five -->
```

Back

{/exp:store:checkout}

Comment: What version of Store?

Answer (score 1):

The reason was because I had a blank input field for order_email in the form, but hidden from view. This field is only used for those paying with Paypal, not with a CC.

Even though the form contained order_email at the top of the page, it wasn't passing through to the database because this was blank.

I solved it by passing the value as

```
value="{order_email}"
```

Another option here, as Adrian pointed out below: Remove this email field all together since the email is remembered from the previous page. I added it because I thought this email field was required for paypal to process the order and had to be the users paypal account email address (I was light on the coffee this day).

Order email, is order email, the email associated with the order - and has nothing to do with the users paypal account email address. Paypal handles that. The "order_email" field is required for all gateways... It just tells store this field is valid and to process the order with the configured gateway. With the Paypal Express gateway, I simply thought the order_email had to be the email associated with Paypal - and gave the user the option to add a different email when they chose paypal as a payment method. Completely unnecessary. I opted for removing the second email field, and now display a simple "pay with paypal" button on the page.

Comment: Why are you using a hidden field at all? You can just leave it out altogether and Store will remember the email from the previous page.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, you are right - I used this field because I thought the email address associated with paypal had to be inputted here. I can remove the email field, since it comes from the previous page, and just include the "pay with paypal" Submit button to send the payment through when they choose that option. Simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your checkout template code? Do you have something like this in checkout2.html?

```
<div class="infield {if error:order_email}error{/if}">
    <label for="order_email">Email</label>
    {field:order_email} {error:order_email}
</div>
```

Comment: I've posted the checkout template. The order_email field is there.

Answer (score 0):

You might try removing order_email from your `require` parameter: the [checkout docs](https://exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html) imply it's already run through validation and maybe requirement too.

Comment: I tried that - the only thing I am seeing is that I have a field for order_email for paypal, if someone chooses that as the method of payment over stripe. This isn't filled in if they are paying with stripe. So I'm not sure it's being passed through, even though it is already in the template as text.